# Error accessing DateTime List. "Index out of bounds" or "contains no elements"

Tags: c#

I have some trouble and i don't really understand why, nor can I seem to find a solution.

I have a list of datetime values. I'm trying to extract the first and last value from the list in order to calculate the total amount of hours between them. Below is the code that shows how the list is generated. The rest of the code works, thus I know that the list contains elements. The problem occurs at the 5 lines of code at the bottom.

```cs
List<DateTime> datesList = new List<DateTime>();
List<string> distancesList = new List<string>();
DateTime dateFromDb = new DateTime();
string distanceFromDb;
int distancesCounter1 = 0;
int distancesCounter2 = 0;
double numberOfDistances;
double sittingPercentage;
double standingPercentage;
SqlDataReader reader;

dbConnection.Open();
using (SqlCommand selectCmd =
     new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Measurements where DateTime between @fromTime And @now ORDER BY DateTime DESC", dbConnection))
{
    selectCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("now", now);
    selectCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("fromTime", fromTime);
    reader = selectCmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        dateFromDb = reader.GetDateTime(reader.GetOrdinal("DateTime"));
        distanceFromDb = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("Distance"));
        datesList.Add(dateFromDb);
        distancesList.Add(distanceFromDb);
    }
        reader.Close();
        dbConnection.Close();
}

foreach (var dist in distancesList)
{
    if (Convert.ToInt16(dist) <= 85)
    {
        distancesCounter1++;
    }
    else
    {
        distancesCounter2++;
    }
}

numberOfDistances = distancesList.Count;
sittingPercentage = distancesCounter1 / numberOfDistances * 100;
standingPercentage = distancesCounter2 / numberOfDistances * 100;
chartPositions.Series["Sitting"].Points.AddXY("Position", sittingPercentage);
chartPositions.Series["Standing"].Points.AddXY("Position", standingPercentage);

TimeSpan totalHours = new TimeSpan();
DateTime time1 = datesList.First();
DateTime time2 = datesList.Last();
totalHours = time1 - time2;
textBoxTime.Text = totalHours.TotalHours.ToString();
```

I have tried the above example and the below example:

```
TimeSpan totalHours = new TimeSpan();
DateTime time1 = datesList[0];
DateTime time2 = datesList[datesList.Count - 1];
totalHours = time1 - time2;
textBoxTime.Text = totalHours.TotalHours.ToString();
```

With a foreach loop i print the elements of the List to a listbox:

```
foreach (var date in datesList)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(date);
        }


        //TimeSpan totalHours = new TimeSpan();
        //DateTime time1 = datesList.First();
        //DateTime time2 = datesList.Last();
        //totalHours = time1 - time2;
        //textBoxTime.Text = totalHours.TotalHours.ToString();
```

[image]

I hope you can help me, thanks in advance!

Comment: Good place to start with the debugger. Error indicates datelist doesnt have anything so check what happened with sql statement.

Comment: Shouldn't this line "DateTime time2 = datesList[datesList.Count];" be "DateTime time2 = datesList[datesList.Count - 1];"

Comment: *thus I know that the list contains elements*, your code says it does not. No offence but I trust the code more =). I am pretty sure your `datesList` has no element

Comment: And what's the result of "SELECT * FROM Measurements where DateTime between fromTime And now ORDER BY DateTime DESC"

Comment: As the edit above shows, the list does contain elements.

Comment: The version with the loop filling the listbox only shows that the list contains elements at one point. Is it possible that the code runs multiple times, sometimes resulting in an empty list and sometimes not? You should in any case make the code robust enough to deal with an empty list. Just check that the list is not empty before trying to access its elements.

Comment: The comments already explain the problems with the code. `datesList[datesList.Count]` *guarantees* an out-of-range exception. You claim the problem is caused when trying to access the first element but you *didn't* post the exception, which would include the call stack.

Comment: List works. That's a fact. If the list contained any items, `List[0]` works. That's a fact. `datesList[datesList.Count]` doesn't work. That's a fact too. `datesList.Count - 0` is equal to `datesList.Count`.  You should inspect the actual values in the debugger when that error occurs, to see which line actually throws, and how many items really are in there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The items in a `List` are numbered from `0` to `Count - 1`.

So, to access the last item, do not use `datesList[datesList.Count]`, but `datesList[datesList.Count - 1]`;

---

Your code should always be prepared to handle an empty list. So, first check whether the list is empty before trying to access it's contents.

```
TimeSpan totalHours = new TimeSpan();

if (datesList.Any())
{

    DateTime time1 = datesList.First();
    DateTime time2 = datesList.Last();
    totalHours = time1 - time2;
}
else
{
    totalHours = TimeSpan.Zero;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer @NineBerry. The error occurs when trying to get the first value in the List.

Comment: @DanielBeck, does the error occur when you run the code shown in NineBerry's answer?

Comment: @RoadWarrior no it works now. Just so that I learn, why is it that the code works with this branching statement since all it does is check if the list contains any elements? Shouldn't the List contain the elements with or without the check?

Comment: @DanielBeck My suspicion is that the code is executed multiple times when you execute the application. In some cases the list is empty, in some cases it contains elements. You can find out easily by setting a breakpoint.